# Automating Flash Applications with out rebuilding application code with flash api

Tags: automated-testing, flash

I have a flex based application and I need to automate it to reduce the manual repeatitive work. I am aware of few automation tools but all of them need the application to be rebuild.

Currently we do not have access to code to create a test environment and perform automation.

So I am looking for performing automation on the site as it is.

Please suggest any open source tool

Thanks,
Sashi

Answer (score 2):

While you would want to use one of the tools recommended by Daniel, you also might need a debugging version of Adobe Flash. Look it up on Adobe's site and you'll find a debug version. We use it with TestComplete by SmartBear and it works fine with debug version of Flash, while complaining on regular flash.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SQA.

The open source answer I think would be Selenium RC:

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/

I wasn't sure if this would work at first, but I found this article on Adobe's site about how to do it:

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/flash_selenium.html

The other option I could direct you to (though it's not open-source) is Ranorex. I use it for a  lot of browser automation and love it. It's a little more accessible and requires less coding ability for core functionality:

http://www.ranorex.com/product/automated-ui-testing-of-flash-flex-applications.html

Comment: Thank you Daniel. Can you please confirm if we There is need to compile all the code into your app, or link to a SWC file at compile time. Since I dont have access to application code , i cant compile.

Comment: While I can't say from experience (I haven't had to automate flex applications before), both options seem to be running against the SWF, not the SWC, so I think you're good. Sorry that I don't have a more certain answer than that.